# Any tag pagination page (except the 1st page) loads index.php template instead of tag.php

Tags: theme-development, templates, pagination, tags, template-hierarchy

Created my first custom theme from scratch and I'm trying to do a listing of all posts with the same tag.

In `tag.php` I display all posts with that specific tag via a `WP_Query` and I'm trying to implement the pagination for that listing (using `paginate_links()`). Page links seem to be outputted correctly. Also the first page looks good.

What I don't understand is that when I go on to the next tag page (or to any of the page links outputted from my `tag.php` template e.g. `http://127.0.0.1/wp_site/tag/test_tag/page/2/`) the content from `index.php` is being displayed.

What am I actually missing for displaying the subsequent tag pages correctly?

### `tag.php` template CODE:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <h1 class="entry-title">Other entries related to &#39;<?php single_tag_title(); ?>&#39;</h1>
                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
                    <div class="entry-content"></div><!-- .entry-content -->
                </article><!-- #post-## -->
                <div>   
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                       <?php
                            $tagId = get_queried_object()->term_id;
                            $postType = get_post_type();
                        ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php
                        $htmlOutput = '';
                        /* the 'terms' ID is the testimonial category parent id */
                        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                        $args = [
                              'post_type' => 'testimonials-widget', 
                              'tag_id' => $tagId,
                              'posts_per_page' => 3,
                              'paged' => $paged,
                              'tax_query' => [
                                    [
                                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                        'field'    => 'term_id',
                                        'terms'    => '8',
                                    ]
                                ],
                        ];    
                        $post_query = new WP_Query($args);
                        $contentHtml = '';
                        if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
                            $posts = $post_query->posts;
                            foreach($posts as $post) {
                                // generate html output
                            }
                        }
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                        echo $contentHtml;
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="mainContentWrapperCls">
                <?php 
                    echo paginate_links( array(
                        'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
                        'total'        => $post_query->max_num_pages,
                        'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
                        'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
                        'show_all'     => false,
                        'type'         => 'plain',
                        'end_size'     => 2,
                        'mid_size'     => 1,
                        'prev_next'    => true,
                        'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( '&lt;&lt; Previous page', 'text-domain' ) ),
                        'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Next page &gt;&gt;', 'text-domain' ) ),
                        'add_args'     => false,
                        'add_fragment' => '',
                    ) );
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php else : ?>
                <h1>No posts were found.</h1> 
            <?php endif; ?>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- .wrap -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

> ***Note:*** I created a new query with `WP_Query` in `tag.php`. The reason why I did this is because I didn't know how to generate the type of pagination I needed (`<Prev 1 2 3 Next>` style) via `paginate_links()`, with the main query.

### Theme `functions.php` CODE:

```
<?php
    function myCustomThemeScriptEnqueue() {
        // Theme stylesheet, js
        wp_enqueue_style('myCustomTheme-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    }

    function myCustomThemeThemeSetup() {
        add_theme_support('menus');
        add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
    }

    function nllTagFilter($query) {
        if ($query->is_main_query()) {
            if ($query->is_tag) {
                $post_types = get_post_types();
                $query->set('post_type', $post_types);
            }
        }
    }

    add_action('pre_get_posts','nllTagFilter');

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myCustomThemeScriptEnqueue');
    add_action('init', 'myCustomThemeThemeSetup');

    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 );
?>
```

This is my theme's file-structure so far:

[image: custom theme file structure]

Comment: what is the code of tag.php?

Comment: When you say *I display all posts with that specific tag via a WP_Query*, do you mean you are creating a new query in the template and not using the default main query?

Comment: How do you know `index.php` template file is being loaded? Use the plugin [What the file](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/) to check if it is indeed `index.php`. It's possible that what you are thinking as content from `index.php` is actually from other template parts. Also, `nllTagFilter` function doesn't change default template loading behavior, it only includes all post types (even custom post types) with the same tag. So either some other CODE from `functions.php` or a plugin is changing this. Try disabling all plugins, or update your question with the CODE of `functions.php`.

Comment: @Michael Please see my edit; added the full code in both tag.php and functions.php Thanks!

Comment: @Milo Thank is correct. It does seem like an ugly way of doing it but I didn't know how to display the type of pagination I needed (<Prev 1 2 3 Next>) via paginate_links, without a WP_Query. (also please check my udated post; added full code from both tag.php and functions.php)

Comment: @Fayaz I installed the 'What the file' plugin and can confirm that on the subsequent pages it's index.php. Also, I replaced the real name of my site with 'wp_site' but it was properly installed, has .htaccess and the correct Settings for Site Address (URL). So maybe that only leaves the fact that I created a new query with WP_Query in tag.php (please see my edited post with the code); the reason why I did this is because I didn't know how to generate the type of pagination I needed (<Prev 1 2 3 Next> style) via paginate_links(), with the main query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Overall CODE issues:

Your CODE is so wrong in so many ways that I shouldn't even attempt to address them here. I suggest you study [Official WordPress Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/) properly before doing these sort of customizations.

For the sake of the context, I'm ignoring other issues within your CODE and touching only the issues below:

### 1. Why `index.php` template is being loaded?

First of all, you are getting wrong pagination from your erroneous CODE (check the explanation below). So apart from the first tag page, all the other tag pages are nonexistent (i.e. you need to add more posts to the tag to get more tag pages).

Secondly, According to WordPress Template loading rules, `404.php` template should be loaded for those non-existing tag pages (as you probably know, in HTTP, 404 is the **Page Not Found Error CODE**). However, since you don't have a `404.php` template in your theme, `index.php` template is being loaded, as it is the **ultimate fallback template** in a WordPress theme.

Now, if you create a `404.php` template, then you'll see that it'll be loaded instead of `index.php` for those non-existing tag pages.

Study [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) properly for a better understanding of how different templates are loaded for different content.

### 2. Fixing the wrong pagination:

As I said above, you're getting nonexistent tag page numbers within your pagination. To remove those nonexistent page numbers from the pagination, you need to delete the

```
'total' => $post_query->max_num_pages
```

line from the `paginate_links` function call in `tag.php` template file.

The reason is:

1. `$post_query` is your custom query, not the main query that should determine the number of pages the tag archive has. You even used `wp_reset_postdata()` before `paginate_links` function call, so no reason to use that variable here.
2. The `total` parameter of the `paginate_links` function by default gets the value of the main WP_Query's `max_num_pages` property. So deleting it will automatically provide the correct value for the pagination from the main WP_Query object.

### 3. Pagination without new `WP_Query`:

In the comments you said:

> The reason why I did this is because I didn't know how to generate the type of pagination I needed (`<Prev 1 2 3 Next>` style) via `paginate_links()`, with the main query.

Well, you don't need a completely new `WP_Query` just for a different pagination style. In fact, the `paginate_links()` function don't need the main `WP_Query` object at all!

So all you need for your desired pagination style is:

```
echo paginate_links( array(
    'end_size'     => 2,
    'mid_size'     => 1,
    'prev_text'    => __( '&lt;&lt; Previous page', 'text-domain' ),
    'next_text'    => __( 'Next page &gt;&gt;', 'text-domain' ) 
) );
```

All the other values are being collected by default (including the main `WP_Query` object)! So you can remove your new `WP_Query` object in the `tag.php` template entirely. Check the [`paginate_links` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/).

Having said that, there can be only one more thing you may want (judging from your comments):

### 4. Control the number of posts per tag page:

You don't need a new `WP_Query` for this either. This can be easily achieved from the following CODE in `functions.php`:

```
function tag_post_per_page_filter( $query ) { 
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) { 
        if ( $query->is_tag ) { 
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 3 );
        }   
    }   
}   

add_action('pre_get_posts','tag_post_per_page_filter');
```

Basically it sets the `posts_per_page` to `3` in the main `WP_Query` object for the tag pages. That's all.

Comment: Dude you are awesome; thanks for the effort. Everything worked like a charm.

Comment: Excellent breakdown of many common mistakes for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to add, in case it's helpful to others: If you pass the 'total' argument, it will display more pages than necessary. :

```
$args = array('total'=>20);
```

On the blog top page (index.php), I had limited the display to 20 pages tops (this client has hundreds of articles). 5 was too little - wanted to make sure Google picks up more than that.

However, when i copied this to tag.php or category.php to achieve exactly what the OP wanted to achieve, I left those variables in by default. I figured even if i set the max to 20, it would show less if there's less articles, right? **Wrong**.

It turns out that if I ask for 20 pages displayed, even if there's 5 pages worth of articles under a certain category, it just overrides that.

When I hit page 6 within a specific category, it would display the contents of my 404.php because there was no more than 25 articles under a certain category (5 per page is the display limit).

I assumed: "Oh it must be loading the pagination count for ALL articles on the blog, not just this category!" I went in a wild goose chase looking for answers on how I can limit this function to show the current category pages only.

Fayaz's words above gave me the hint I needed:

> Well, you don't need a completely new WP_Query just for a different pagination style. In fact, the paginate_links() function don't need the main WP_Query object at all! Commenting out the 'total' array key did the trick.

```
<?php
            $pages_args = array(
                'prev_next'=>false,
                // 'total'=>20
            );

            $pagelinks = paginate_links($pages_args);
            echo $pagelinks;
            ?>
```